# Qt6 Android how to call Toast via JNI?

Tags: android, qt, java-native-interface, qt6

What am I doing wrong in my function when trying to display this Toast?

```cpp
QNativeInterface::QAndroidApplication::runOnAndroidMainThread([=]() {
                    QJniEnvironment env;
                    jclass clazz = env.findClass("android/widget/Toast");
                    QJniObject displayText = QJniObject::fromString("Hello world");
                    jint timeout = 10;
                    QJniObject callableToast = QJniObject::callStaticMethod<jobject>(
                        clazz,
                        "makeText",
                        QNativeInterface::QAndroidApplication::context(),
                        displayText.object<jstring>(),
                        timeout
                    );

                    callableToast.callMethod<void>("show");
                                     QNativeInterface::QAndroidApplication::context());
    }).waitForFinished();
```

This keeps failing with:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no static method "Landroid/widget/Toast;.makeText(Landroid/content/Context;Ljava/lang/String;I)Ljava/lang/Object;"
```

The args and return type seem correct to me based on [Android Toast docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast#makeText(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20int)). I've also tried changing the return type to `jclass` which fails with a similar error.

FWIW, I've also tried explicitly setting the signature, and it fails with a similar error:

```cpp
QJniObject callableToast = QJniObject::callStaticMethod<jobject>(
                        clazz,
                        "makeText",
// "Landroid/content/Context;Ljava/lang/String;I)Landroid/widget/Toast;"
                        "(Landroid/content/Context;Ljava/lang/CharSequence;I)Landroid/widget/Toast",
                        QNativeInterface::QAndroidApplication::context(),
                        displayText.object<jstring>(),
                        timeout
                    );
```

I also see this in the logs, but don't know if it is valuable:

```
W System  : ClassLoader referenced unknown path:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved it:

```cpp
QJniObject toast = QJniObject::callStaticObjectMethod(
                        "android/widget/Toast",
                        "makeText",
                        "(Landroid/content/Context;Ljava/lang/CharSequence;I)"
                        "Landroid/widget/Toast;",
                        QNativeInterface::QAndroidApplication::context(),
                        displayText.object<jstring>(),
                        timeout
                    );

                    if (toast.isValid()) {
                        qDebug() << "Toast is valid";
                        toast.callMethod<void>("show");
                    } else {
                        qDebug() << "Toast JNI object not valid";
                    }
```